# Documenting Mutually Exclusive Query Parameters in API Blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint

I'm documenting a public API that has a method named `/findGuild` that takes a mandatory `key` parameter and one of the following parameters:

1. `byPlayer`
2. `byName`

It *must* have either `byPlayer` or `byName`; My question is: **How do I indicate that `byPlayer` and `byName` are mutually exclusive, but one is mandatory?**

---

Right now, I have the following in my `.apib` for this Resource:

```
### GET /findGuild{?byName,byPlayer,key}

+ Parameters
  + byName: `YourGuild` (string, optional) - Search for the Guild by its name.
  + byPlayer: (string, optional) -  Search for Guild by a player. Does not seem to work.
  + key: `ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff` (string, required) - The user's API key.

+ Response 200 (application/json)

    + Attributes (object)
      + guild (string) - The guild id or null.
      + success (boolean) - Should be true.

    + Body

            {
              "guild": "ffffffffffffffffffffffff",
              "success": true
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid (but not totally sure) API Blueprint is not capable of expressing this kind of relationship at the moment.

What I can surely tell you is that, according to [public roadmap](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint-rfcs/pull/3), URI Parameters will be replaced with an [MSON object](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson), which supports the [scenario](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson#mutually-exclusive-properties) you're asking for.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, so the best I can do right now is explain in plain English language. I'm looking forward to those changes!